# Per-machine shared memory pool in Celery or similar multiprocessing system

Tags: python, pyspark, multiprocessing, celery, shared-memory

I have a set of tasks that I would like to run in parallel across multiple machines, each with multiple cores. My main challenge is that these tasks require read-only access to a 12GB data set which must be accessed quickly by the worker threads/processes, so keeping that data in memory is a must. Systems that isolate workers into separate processes would need to copy this memory for each worker, which is unacceptable - I don't have machines with 12GB of spare memory per core.

PySpark's "broadcast" function nearly solved my problem, but PySpark serializes the data to a string as it distributes it across the network, and one of Spark's subsystems balks at the huge data size and just quits while serializing the data.

I'm on Linux so I can get my data into shared memory via ramfs, but I still need a way to get machine-level granularity. Setting up the shared memory and distributing a reference to it should happen once per machine, not once per task or once per worker. I'm struggling to find a way to do this on *any* distributed task library (Celery, ipyparallel, etc). Am I stuck rolling my own task distributor with Python's multiprocessing?

Comment: Maybe Apache Arrow? https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2017/08/08/plasma-in-memory-object-store/

Comment: also: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/index.html

Comment: Interesting @juanpa.arrivillaga! Looks like Arrow provides a method of sharing the data within each machine (my method was not going to be as tidy), and Ray provides a related worker/task execution framework. But how do I tell Ray "here's a function, run it once _per machine_"? Same thing I was struggling with in Celery.